# Wordpress the_field(); convert to number

Tags: php, wordpress, string

```
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php the_field('home_player'); ?></td>
      <td><?php displayresult(the_field('result')); ?></td>
      <td><?php the_field('away_player'); ?></td>
      <td><?php date('dS F Y', the_field('date')); ?></td>
      <td><?php the_field('board'); ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is the code I am working on. I've stored the date as a timestamp and I'm trying to convert it using the date function in php. As writing this it occured to me that it could be a string instead of number. I tested it, and turns out the_field only returns strings. Is there any way to convert it to a number?

Comment: Before anyone asks I tried "the_field('date') + 0"

Comment: By timestamp you mean a unix timestamp, a numeric value such as `1453577004`, only that you have it in string form, `'1453577004'`? You don’t neet to convert it to a number to pass it as second parameter to the `date` function – PHP’s automatic type conversion will handle that.

Comment: You mean [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?